# Trying to check if a scrollbar is present in tablet using Selenium (Appium)

Tags: selenium, appium

I have a method which checks if a scrollbar is present in a tablet page.
This is what my method looks like:

```
    public void ifScrollbarispresent() {
    String execScript = "return document.documentElement.scrollHeight>document.documentElement.clientHeight;";
    JavascriptExecutor scrollBarPresent = (JavascriptExecutor) session.driver;
    Boolean ifscrollbarpresent = (Boolean) (scrollBarPresent.executeScript(execScript));
    if (ifscrollbarpresent == true) {
        System.out.print("Scrollbar is present.");
    } else if (ifscrollbarpresent == false){
        System.out.print("Scrollbar is not present.");
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method is not implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

This is my following appium log:

```
[MJSONWP (b44cde9b)] Calling AppiumDriver.execute() with args: ["return document.documentElement.scrollHeight>document.documentElement.clientHeight;",[],"b44cde9b-bf58-4671-83bb-c169315c66ee"]
[MJSONWP (b44cde9b)] Encountered internal error running command: NotImplementedError: Method is not implemented
 at AndroidDriver.extensions.execute (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/commands/execute.js:12:9)
```

Can anyone please suggest what goes wrong? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

remove `return` and try:

```java
String execScript = "document.documentElement.scrollHeight>document.documentElement.clientHeight;";
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

my demo code:

```java
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://github.com/");

String execScript = "return document.documentElement.scrollHeight>document.documentElement.clientHeight;";
JavascriptExecutor scrollBarPresent = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

// Notice this
System.out.println(scrollBarPresent.executeScript(execScript).toString());

Boolean ifscrollbarpresent = (Boolean) (scrollBarPresent.executeScript(execScript));
if (ifscrollbarpresent == true) {
    System.out.print("Scrollbar is present.");
} else if (ifscrollbarpresent == false) {
    System.out.print("Scrollbar is not present.");
}
```

running log:

```
true
Scrollbar is present.
```

Comment: @Piku Could you give more running log and code? I guess that maybe not scrollbar but others go wrong. I've run a demo, and verified the `execScript` worked well. The answer has edited, please check it out again.

Comment: And just one thing, I am not using chrome, I am using it on emulator from my android studio. @Peter Quan

Comment: sorry, @Piku, I have uninstalled Appium on my computer, so it is not easy for me to continue debugging the code. However, I have other suggestion, if you would like just to automate webpage using Chrome on a mobile device, rather than test native app on android, please know another way ["Chrome allows users to emulate Chrome on a mobile device from the desktop version of Chrome". ](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation)